# How to do Collapse/expand CellTable in GWT 2.4

Tags: java, gwt

I would like to have a CellTable with Collapse/Expand rows. I have seen that in GWT 2.5 has a way to do that but I've not been able to find a way to do that in GWT 2.4.

I tried to do with CellTree, but CellTree only supports one column and I need 3 or 4 columns in the child node.

Answer (score 0):

The [Smart GWT](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#grid_memo_rows) library has what you are looking for. Other than that, you probably have to build it yourself. If you start a new project now, just run with GWT 2.5 RC and replace it with the final version once available, there won't be too much changes anymore.

Comment: It is not a new project. It is a update. And I should not mixed GWT layouts or components with Smart GWT layouts or components.